# What exactly is "is_paginated" ? Django Documentation

Tags: python, django

I've been learning Django for the past couple of months and have found out that the documentation is not very good, or maybe I don't know how to use it, but on many occasions I find myself doubtful when looking where everything comes from.

As long as I know, is_paginated is a boolean in the context that returns True if the results are paginated, I found this information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/

But in that link from the documentation says it is from the Multiple Object Mixin, and in a Django youtube tutorial I've seen he uses it within a generic class-based DetaiView template, so I've tried to look in the documentation for it and I could not find anything that satisfies my curiosity, maybe I'm not seeing something but I don't like just copying code without knowing where exactly it comes from and what it does.

Comment: Django's docs are some of the best i've ever used. [Half way down the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data) you've included it tells you what `is_paginated` is

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation:

> **is_paginated:** A boolean representing whether the results are paginated. Specifically, this is set to False if no page size has been
> specified, or if the available objects do not span multiple pages.

To know more follow the link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data